# Создание микросервиса API Gateway в существующем проекте python

Tags: python, flask, rest, микросервисы

Чтобы объяснить контекст, в настоящее время я разрабатываю микросервисное приложение с 4 частями:

- Publishers [с симулятором].
- Queue system
- Receivers (которые также выполняют локальную обработку) [на Python].
- Фронт-энд, который получает данные с помощью REST API на приемнике [на React].

Чтобы настроить gateway API между receiver и фронт-эндом, я создала несколько thread в receiver: первый который получает данные и обрабатывает и второй работает с Flask.

Кажется, что это работает, но я уверена, что это не лучшее решение... Возможно ли создать  Gateway API как самостоятельный микросервис, а не как "дополнение" к Receiver ?

Comment: В мире нет ничего невозможного. Через репликацию СУБД / совместный доступ/ синхронизацию к  оной можно понаделать всякого.

Comment: Оправданность подобного решения может быть под вопросом в контексте логики работы Receivers и API. Если между ними пересечений много, требуется высокая синхронность работы - создание отдельного микросервиса однозначно вызовет технические проблемы. В противном случае, при низкой степени синхронности и интеграции - можно и разделить.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Между получателем и отправителем нет реальной синхронизации, поскольку они проходят через систему очереди, в которой хранятся сообщения.
Итак, если мы отделим API Gateway, какой метод получения информации от получателя будет наилучшим? Sockets, RPC или что-то другое?

Comment: @Natalia я бы рассматривал данный вопрос более комплексно. Наилучшим решением является всегда то, которое точно будет работать для вашей задачи и стоить вам при этом не заоблачно дорого в части ресурсов. Следует учитывать не только особенности самой системы в части функциональных требований, но и опыт ваших ведущих разработчиков, потенциальные трудозатраты и готовность заказчика платить деньги за всё веселье. Паттерны проектирования микросервисов - больше миф в реалии современной IT индустрии имхо...